# Is there a way to check if a PyQt5 window is open and delay another instance accordingly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am new with Python3 and PyQt5. I made a PyQt5 template for showing notifications. So in the end I have a function [notification()] which displays a notification on-screen.

But the problem is that when I have multiple invocations of notification(), simulataneously, only the first one shows and the program then exits. (there is a test case in the end - notice how only the first one pops up

Is there a way for me to be able to halt the second notification until the first one completes, and then invoke the function (maybe using flags or something).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout,QLabel,QDesktopWidget,QWidget,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QTimer

class SpecialBG(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setStyleSheet(
                "color: rgba(237,174,28,100%);"
                "background-color: rgba(247,247,247,95%);"
                "text-align: center;"
                "border-radius: 20px;"
                "padding: 0px;"
                )

class SimpleRoundedCorners(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,title,minutes):
        self.title = title 
        self.minutes = minutes

        super(SimpleRoundedCorners, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        QTimer.singleShot(5500, self.exeunt)

    def exeunt(self):
        self.close
        exit()

    def initUI(self):
        winwidth = 650
        winheight = 150

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("SF Pro Display")
        font.setPointSize(20)

        font2 = QFont()
        font2.setFamily("SF Pro Display")
        font2.setPointSize(18)

        VBox = QVBoxLayout()
        roundyround = SpecialBG(self)
        VBox.addWidget(roundyround)

        VBox.pyqtConfigure
        self.setLayout(VBox)
        self.setWindowFlags(
                  Qt.FramelessWindowHint
                | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
                | Qt.SplashScreen
                )

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        taskTitle = QLabel(self)
        taskTitle.move(120, 40)
        taskTitle.setFont(font)
        taskTitle.setText(self.title)
        taskTitle.adjustSize()

        timeLeft = QLabel(self)
        timeLeft.move(120, 80)
        timeLeft.setFont(font2)
        timeLeft.setText("in "+str(self.minutes)+" minutes")
        timeLeft.adjustSize()

        self.setGeometry(1260, 5, winwidth, winheight)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple Rounded Corners')
        self.show()

# this is the function
def notification(title,minutes):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    alldone = SimpleRoundedCorners(title,minutes)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# test-cases
notification("notification #1",5)
notification("notification #2",10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some addition to eyllanesc's answer:

It seems you want to encapsulate your qt-app execution in notification function and mean it to be *non-blocking*, which is not happening as QT main loop is executing in main thread. Also you cannot init QT app in non-main thread (as far as I know)

The solution may be to create process for qt-app in separate thread, and block this thread if another one is currently running (e.g. by semaphore). This process and thread will be terminated just after notification will be shown.

Here is how it look like:

```
from subprocess import call
import threading

title1 = "notification #1"
title2 = "notification #2"
m1     = 5
m2     = 10

sem = threading.Semaphore(value=1)


def notify_call(title, minutes) :
    sem.acquire()
    call(["python", "show-notify-qt.py", title, str(minutes)])
    sem.release()


def notify(title, minutes) :
    threading.Thread(target=notify_call, args=(title, minutes)).start()


notify(title1, m1)
print("I'm not blocking!")
notify(title2, m2)
print("I'm still not blocking!")
```

```
# show-notify-qt.py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout,QLabel,QDesktopWidget,QWidget,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QTimer
import sys


class SpecialBG(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setStyleSheet(
                "color: rgba(237,174,28,100%);"
                "background-color: rgba(247,247,247,95%);"
                "text-align: center;"
                "border-radius: 20px;"
                "padding: 0px;"
                )

class SimpleRoundedCorners(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,title,minutes):
        self.title = title 
        self.minutes = minutes

        super(SimpleRoundedCorners, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        QTimer.singleShot(5500, self.exeunt)

    def exeunt(self):
        QApplication.quit()

    def initUI(self):
        winwidth = 650
        winheight = 150

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("SF Pro Display")
        font.setPointSize(20)

        font2 = QFont()
        font2.setFamily("SF Pro Display")
        font2.setPointSize(18)

        VBox = QVBoxLayout()
        roundyround = SpecialBG(self)
        VBox.addWidget(roundyround)

        VBox.pyqtConfigure
        self.setLayout(VBox)
        self.setWindowFlags(
                  Qt.FramelessWindowHint
                | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
                | Qt.SplashScreen
                )

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        taskTitle = QLabel(self)
        taskTitle.move(120, 40)
        taskTitle.setFont(font)
        taskTitle.setText(self.title)
        taskTitle.adjustSize()

        timeLeft = QLabel(self)
        timeLeft.move(120, 80)
        timeLeft.setFont(font2)
        timeLeft.setText("in "+str(self.minutes)+" minutes")
        timeLeft.adjustSize()

        self.setGeometry(1260, 5, winwidth, winheight)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple Rounded Corners')
        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
alldone = SimpleRoundedCorners(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for your this code. I managed to do what I wanted to. Thanks a lot, you are a life-saver!

Comment: No problem @Alaz!
Btw, this is my first reply on stackoverflow and it would be really cool for me if you submit this as the answer:)

Comment: Sure, no problem. It was also my first time posting a question on this site, and I have to hand it to you, the responses are neat and speedy!

Comment: Anyway, would you bother explaining the answer a bit. As stated, I am a bit new, and although I understood it a tiny bit; more details would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Sure, but I have no idea what details do you actually need:) You should ask something more specific to make me possible to answer it.

If u re new to programming itself u need to take some basic courses, and I guess Qt is not the best starting point

Comment: I am **not like new new**, I have dealt with gui w/ python using tkinter. But I was unable to create what I wanted to using it. Thus I turned to pyqt5 which is loads better. I wanted to try and understand what you did with threading and handling the notifications. That is something I had never seen/done before.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Your first problem was that u did not correctly exit QApp, and tried to run another QApp instance which is restricted by Qt. You can fix it and everything will work, but your notification function will block your program until QApp finishes its job (basically, QApp.exec() invokes a event loop until it catches end-event in your timeout function). So you need to run QApp.exec() in parallel, i.e. in separate thread or process. QApp cannot be invoked in non-main thread, so you need to invoke it in another process (which call actually do)

Comment: Also, you want to delay another app invoking if another one is running. There is no such easy way to check another process'es status. But you can easy control your threads, so you wrap the process-spawning function and run it in another thread. Semaphore is the simpliest way to control max number of simultaneously running threads. We just say that no more than 1 separate thread can run in same time. If u call notify() 2 times, one thread will start to work, and another will wait until first call release(). You can read more about semaphores externally, they are not too hard to understand.

Comment: also, here we use the fact that subprocess.call itself iis blocking function(it will block corresponding thread until invoked process dies)

Comment: Actually, this is not indented to be state-of-the-art solution for such tasks, it just seems to fit good for your needs. Usually, creating separate app instances or mixing frameworks is not good idea. If u can, use single event loop / app instance

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the explaination. I read it and the docs related to the modules you used, and thus I understood it quite a bit. I tweaked around with your solution, and editted it to not use `threading`, and now the whole thing is **speedy** too. Thanks a bunch for sticking around and replying to all of my _amateur questions_.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `exit()` that is not defined, you should use `sys.exit()`, but it is still an error since with that function the complete application would be closed since that is its function, instead you just have to close the QApplication:

```
# ...
class SimpleRoundedCorners(QWidget):
    # ...
    def exeunt(self):
        QApplication.quit()
    # ...
# this is the function
def notification(title, minutes):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    alldone = SimpleRoundedCorners(title, minutes)
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I was able to string a little more code from @v3arms code and managed to do what I wanted. Thanks an absolute tonne!